# Converting unicode to string Java

Tags: java, string, unicode

I wrote an app that get a string from a server, this string is not in English so the server sends a string that represents the Unicode values of the characters.

Is there a method in some class that takes a string representing a Unicode value (string of the format `"\uXXXX"`) and returns the Unicode character corresponding to this value?

I tried the answers for the other questions. When I tried it on a regular project it worked but on mt android app it causes the app to stop working.

Comment: I would use UTF-8 to encode and decode the String.  Using the `\uXXXX` only makes sense in Java code IMHO.

Comment: There are many string formats that use `\u`. What format is the server supposed to be returning to you? If it's JSON, which seems most likely, you should use a standard JSON parser, which will take care of turning string literal escapes like `\u` into normal Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what Unicodes you want to eliminate, you should use `replace("\uXXXX","")` method.